# Table - how to complete the line at the end?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

How to complete the line following the cell Program Program, please?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage

\usepackage{dcolumn}       
\usepackage{booktabs}      
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
   
\begin{document}

    
     \begin{table}[ht!] \catcode`\-=12
    \caption{A}
    \scriptsize
    \renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}\scriptsize}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} 

%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{2}{C} >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}Cc*{3}{C}{C}}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}\Xhline{1.2pt}%
    \multirowcell{4}{Q} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[3]} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[5]} \\[0.4ex]

    \cline{2-10}

    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PPPP}}

     &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{P\\ a}} & %

    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{S \\ F \\ D}} &

%
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{D }}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{D\\ D\\D}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{D\\ D\\D}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{F\\ F\\F}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Program \\ Program}} \\[1ex]

    \cline{2-3}

    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{II}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{III}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]

    \Xhline{1.2pt}%
    &&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\makecell{$P$ \\ $[$days$]$}&   \multicolumn{8}{c}{AAAA}\\
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\hline
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\makecell{$V$\\ SS}&    71.7755&    21.74(50)&  &   15.5(7)&21.1(16)    &   15.51&  15.71&  15.34\\
[-10pt]
\\
     \Xhline{1.2pt}%
     \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's code, a `\multicolumn{1}{c|}` is lacking.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
\usepackage{dcolumn}       
\usepackage{booktabs}      
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
   
\begin{document}

    
     \begin{table}[ht!] \catcode`\-=12
    \caption{A}
    \scriptsize
    \renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}\scriptsize}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} 

%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{2}{C} >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}Cc*{3}{C}{C}}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}\Xhline{1.2pt}%
    \multirowcell{4}{Q} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[3]} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[5]} \\[0.4ex]

    \cline{2-10}

    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PPPP}}

     &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{P\\ a}} & %

    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{S \\ F \\ D}} &

%
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{D }}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{D\\ D\\D}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{D\\ D\\D}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{F\\ F\\F}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Program \\ Program \\Program}} \\[1ex]

    \cline{2-3}

    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{II}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{III}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]

    \Xhline{1.2pt}%
    &&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\makecell{$P$ \\ $[$days$]$}&   \multicolumn{8}{c}{AAAA}\\
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\hline
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\makecell{$V$\\ SS}&    71.7755&    21.74(50)&  &   15.5(7)&21.1(16)    &   15.51&  15.71&  15.34\\
[-10pt]
\\
     \Xhline{1.2pt}%
     \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Remark*: It's much simpler with `nicematrix`.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular*}` of `nicematrix`.

The environment `{NiceTabular}` is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` but with new features.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both vertically and horizontally with the command `\Block`. The vertical rules are not drawn in the blocks. The horizontal rules (all drawn by the key `hlines` are not drawn in the blocks.

You seem to want a special rule on the right the tabular. I have drawn after the construction of the tabular with a Tikz instruction (which uses the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage

\usepackage{dcolumn}       
\usepackage{booktabs}      
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
   
\begin{document}

    
\begin{table}[ht!] 
\caption{A}
\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=3pt}
\hrule
\vspace{\doublerulesep}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c*{9}{|c}}[hlines]
\Block{3-1}{Q} & \Block{1-2}{[1]} && \Block{1-2}{[2]} && [3] & \Block{1-3}{[4]} &&& [5] \\
& \Block{1-2}{PPPP} & & \Block{2-1}{P\\ a} & \Block{2-1}{S\\ F\\ D} & \Block{2-1}{D} & \Block{2-1}{D \\ D \\ D} &
\Block{2-1}{D \\ D \\ D} & \Block{2-1}{F\\ F\\ F} & \Block{2-1}{Program\\ Program} \\
& II & III \\
\Block{}{$P$\\ [days]} & \Block{1-*}{AAAA} \\
\Block{}{$V$\\ SS} & \Block{1-*}{}71.7755 & 21.74(50) && 15.5(7) & 21.1(16) & 15.51 & 15.71 & 15.34 \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (1-|11) -- (4-|11) ;
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}
    
    
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you very much. Could I ask a question about the errors I obtained, please? I added them to my question.

Comment: I think you have not the latest version of the package `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation.

Comment: This is not sufficient? sudo apt install texlive?

Comment: It should. But be careful, your error messages seem to say that you have written `\begin{NiceTabular}` instead of `begin{NiceTabular*}`.

Comment: I have written NiceTabular*. After 'sudo apt install texlive', I sill obtain errors.

Comment: I sent it. Thanks

Comment: I am using February 5, 2021 version and could not compile either. Solved by using `\tikz \draw (row-1-|col-11) -- (row-4-|col-11) ;`  instead of   `\tikz \draw (1-|11) -- (4-|11) ; `

Comment: @Simon Dispa: Yes. Since the version 5.11 (February 22, 2021), you can either use the syntax `(row-1-|col-11)` or the syntax `(1-|11)`. Both syntaxes are available and the old syntax will never be deprecated (for technical reasons: `nicematrix` have to create first the nodes `row-1`, `col-11`, etc. and then the nodes `1`, etc.).

Comment: I uninstalled the TeX Live and installed it back; however, I still have TeX Live 2017/Debian.

Comment: You should ask a new question : How to install TeXLive 2020 on... (with the exact reference of your exploitation system)...

Comment: Could someone find the mistake in the original code, please?